# How can I compare diff in cloned and forked repositories and patch my work?

Tags: git, github

I have a copy of cloned directory on my system and another one is a forked directory. Both of them are same directories, previously I had cloned and worked on it but then decided to fork. Now the problem is all my work is on the cloned directory and I'll have to redo the same work on forked directory.  So how do I find the difference in files between these two directories and only change/add files that are needed?

Side note: I did `git remote rm origin` from the cloned directory since it was not letting me push anything to origin master. So now when I do `git remote -v`, it points towards my repo on github only. I can't compare difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed the remote.

To add a remote:
`git remote add origin yourRemoteUrl`
& then `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder you want to keep working with (the one tracking your fork). Set up everything you care about as a remote to that repository. Specifically, add your local clone as a remote of your local fork:

```
git remote add badclone /path/to/bad/clone/.git
```

Now, you should be able to diff and pull changes:

```
git diff badclone/master
git pull badclone
```